# App crashes because an error in build.gradle Android Studio

Tags: java, android, build, crash

I modified my build.gradle to change its compile sdk version due to android Studio having build problems, When I changed my compile sdk version, I also had to change other compiles in that file. But now my app installs but crashes.. How do I fix that?? Is it because of the versions I use in my libraries??

build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force "junit:junit:4.8.2" } 
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.master.android:glideimageview:1.0'
    implementation files('C:/Users/Luis Alonso/Documents/Trabajos/ExpoINGENIERIA 2018/curso-android-codejavu-master/NavigationDrawerConTabs/.idea/libraries/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'

}
```

Logcat error:

```html
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo, PID: 6041
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6868)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6463)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6403)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6868) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6463) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6403) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq
                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 13 more
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a common problem in compiling section which is

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq"

You need 4 steps to solve this

**1. In the gradle file dependencies try to add the following command**

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

**2. Add `multiDexEnabled` true in your `gradle` file**

```
   compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

**3. In the `manifest`, you have to put `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

**4. Last but not least, put the following code in your application class MAKE SURE you didn't miss `MultiDex.install(this);`**

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

If somehow you already did this and still doesn't work then you need to downgrade the `compiledSkVersion` to

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: When i downgraded i got the following error  Error:(13, 5) error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

Comment: Do you think that if I update Android Studio that issue mght be gone?? that issue happened out of nowwhere... that was why I changed compile sdk to 26

Comment: Did you add multidexenabled true in your gradle file?

Comment: Can you try to not updating it? I mean keep your version as previous compileSdkVersion 26 and then try to build project.

Comment: Don't forget to tell me if the error code is changed whenever you did my step. Thank you.

Comment: Same error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Answer (score 0):

First you must replace all **compile** to **implementation** in your dependencies

And then update you location google lib to last version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

Second all library for **com.android.support** must have same version to avoid crash like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

And try to build it again.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex